# Telegram API Бот, который перенаправляет сообщения определенным пользователям, в зависимости от введенных данных

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Добрый день всем участникам форума!
Я совсем новичок, в программирование (5 дней отроду), решил создать телеграмм-бота для решения бизнес задачи. Все,что читал на форуме с примерами клеил в свой файл. Отдельно первая и вторая часть работает. а вот вместе не хочет. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Идея заключается в следующем: Есть у меня продавцы-представители, которые торгуют моим товаром через интернет. Я каждому присвоил номер купона, по которому им начисляется заработок в случае его применения покупателями(это я вижу в админ панеле сайта). В телеграмм- чат у меня приходят все заказы.При применении купона, покупателем в заказе появляется строка (номер купона) и это видит бот, который подключен к этому чату(всех поступающих заказов)Задача: Чтобы тем моим представителям, которые установили себе этот бот и ввели в него номер своего купона каждый раз приходило сообщение о заказе(естевственно не все заказы, а только по примененному их купону)) Как-то так. Отдельно две части работают а вместе происходит какой-то сбой. Я в коде написал комментарии, как я это вижу. Буду признателен за помощь!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
token = '1631839367:AAHquz8GDUSsN9M3o4JRbVIEYhTmeM'
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

admin = '956881599' # Администратор, которому будут дублироватся заказы  с приминением  купона

chatID = '-1001397959811' #Чат где этот бот следит за общими заказами с сайта

kupon = '' # Номер купона который доллжен ввести представитель, чтобы получать уведомления о его применении в заказе


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def cmd_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, " + str(message.from_user.first_name) 
        + "! " + 
         " Я БОТ. Чтобы получать информацию о заказах с использованием твоего купона, отправь сейчас номер твоего купона в этот чат. Укажи правильно 6 цифр, которые тебе присвоил администратор")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_kupon(message):
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_kupon)
    global kupon;
    kupon = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Твой купон " + kupon +" Теперь когда по твоему купону будет произведена покупка, в этот чат прийдет информация об этом.")
 
#Вот тут начинается капец

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: kupon in message.text.lower(), content_types=["text"]) #Когда в чат прийдет сообщшение, содержащее цифры именно этого купона(который ввел данный пользователь) и бот это увидит, должна запустится эта цепочка, но она не запускается
def checkbot_text(message):
     

    bot.send_message(from_user.id, "По Вашему купону произведена покупка!" + message.text[:42]) # Тут представителю должно прийти сообщение(первые 42 символа с заказа сайта из чата) о приминении купона 
    
    bot.forward_message(admin, chatID, message.message_id) # Дублирование целого сообщения администратору

# Я так понимаю, что бот запутался и не понимает какое сообщение ему пересылать и в каком сообщении искать купон

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: уберите токен, а то могут быть шутки)

Comment: он не верный, Вы знаете как мне помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что здесь нужно изменить функцию:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_kupon)
```

на:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, checkbot_text)
```